# cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 2000 milliseconds with 7276200 out of 23000995 bytes received

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

## Description

I'm using Guzzle in my Laravel project. I had a memory crash when I make a request to an API that return a huge payload.

I have this on the top of my `CURL.php` class.  I have get() that I use Guzzle.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\FORCE_IP_RESOLVE;
use GuzzleHttp\DECODE_CONTENT;
use GuzzleHttp\CONNECT_TIMEOUT;
use GuzzleHttp\READ_TIMEOUT;
use GuzzleHttp\TIMEOUT;

class CURL {

    public static function get($url) {

        $client = new Client();
        $options = [
            'http_errors' => true,
            'force_ip_resolve' => 'v4',
            'connect_timeout' => 2,
            'read_timeout' => 2,
            'timeout' => 2,
        ];
        $result = $client->request('GET',$url,$options);
        $result = (string) $result->getBody();
        $result = json_decode($result, true);
        return $result;

    }

    ...

}
```

When I call it like this in my application, it request a large payload (30000)

```
$url = 'http://site/api/account/30000';
$response =  CURL::get($url)['data'];
```

I kept getting this error

> cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 2000 milliseconds with 7276200 out of 23000995 bytes received (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

How do I avoid this?

Should I increase these settings?

```
'connect_timeout' => 2,
'read_timeout' => 2,
'timeout' => 2,
```

Comment: Yes, raise your timeouts. 2 seconds doesn't appear to be long enough.

Comment: ohh ok. I thought that is sth else that cause this error ?

Comment: No. `Operation timed out after 2000 milliseconds with 7276200 out of 23000995 bytes received` sounds like it's able to connect to the remote server, and it has started downloading data, but cut off after `2000 milliseconds`, which is 2 seconds. `read_timeout` and `timeout` needs to be a lot longer. Try anywhere between 30-180 seconds, or just don't specify it and allow it to be the server default.

Comment: Rasing the timeout is always an option. But if the API has pagination parameter available then you should definitely use that. Because most good API's have pagination

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you need to increase `read_timeout` and `timeout`. The error is clear, you don't have enough time to get the response (the server is slow, network or something else, doesn't matter).

If it's possible, increasing the timeouts is the easiest way.

If the server supports pagination, it's a better way to request the data part by part.

Also you can use async queries in Guzzle and send something to your end user while you are waiting for the response from the API.

Answer (score -3):

simply add this in your composer, worked for me !

```
 "require": {
        "ext-curl": "*"
    },
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. This line alone won't resolve a timeout